# Why won't my DIV change to display='none' (onclick JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working at this for a while, but I can't figure out why my DIV can't be changed back to display: none. It starts off at display: none in my CSS file. When you click the button, it changes the style to display = 'block'. I have an exit label which I want to have close the DIV upon clicking it. I can do it with visibility = 'hidden' but I can't see why display = 'none' shouldn't work.

```
 <button class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('abo').style.display = 'block';">Learn More</a>
         <div id="abo">
           <?php include 'about-more.php';?>
           <div id="about-more">
             <h2>Learn More</h2><br>
             <a href="http://youngmarists.org/">For more info on Young Marists</a><br>
             <p>Contributers to this website</p>

             <?php
               foreach($profiles as $profile => $item):
             ?>

             <section class="profile">
               <h4 class="name"><?php echo $item['name'];?></h4>
               <p class="role"><?php echo $item['role'];?></p>
               <img class="profile-img" src="profiles/<?php echo $item['img'];?>"></img>
             </section>

             <?php endforeach;?>

             <i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x" onclick="document.getElementById('abo').style.display = 'none';"; style="position:fixed;top:6%;right:18%;"></i>
           </div>
```

Comment: visibility: hidden actually doesn't work when you make both the button and the exit label visibility instead of display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your code, the closing tag should be `</button>`.  Right now you have `</a>` in there:

```
<button class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('abo').style.display = 'block';">Learn More</a>
```

But it should be:

```
<button class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('abo').style.display = 'block';">Learn More</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p4pun8qz/

Also, there's an extra semi-colon here:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('abo').style.display = 'none';";
```

Try:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('abo').style.display = 'none';"
```

Comment: Seems like there are typos in the question itself.

Comment: Thanks a ton, silliest thing but I just didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have nested your `<i>` tag within the `<button>` and your `display = 'block'` onClick is on the button itself the inside onClick event is never triggered.

You will need to slightly re-arrange your HTML or move the first onClick to somewhere else to fix it. You will see what I mean if you move the `<i>` element out of the `<button>`.

If you didn't intend for the `<button>` tag to be wrapping everything then be sure to close it as its currently left open.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your `<button>` with a `</a>` in the first line. Change the `</a>` to `</button>` and it should work.

You also have a semicolon too many in your `<i>` after the onclick attribute.